# How to add a button to the end of cell Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton

Can someone tell how to add an `UIButton` to the end of rows of the cell? I have a cell with 10 rows, and I want to create a button at the end of the cell programmatically.

Comment: what do you mean a cell with 10 rows? a cell should be a row by itself. Do you mean you have ten cells?

Comment: Lets just say that I want to add a button at the end of cell. That's all

Comment: @Jack, If by cell you mean a tableview cell, then you can create a custom prototype cell and put a button right there and use constraints for alignment. But your question is pretty vague, so I suggest you to specify it.

Comment: @Olter U are right, but if I create a custom prototype it will be repeated 10 times.